# matching up NSDictionary from XML Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml

I have the code below which has ben spat out of an `XML` parse but i'm unsure as to what I should do to consolidate it. How would I add all the 'string' items into an array??

**Parser**:

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.url.net/directory/%@",fileName]]];
                NSDictionary *dict=[XMLParser dictionaryForXMLData:data error:nil];
                NSLog(@"%@",dict);
```

`XMLParser` is a custom class.

**NSLog**:

```
plist =     {
            dict =         {
                key =             (
                                    {
                        text = "\n\n\tmapFile";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tmapPreviewFile";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tmapScale";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tmapper";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tterrain";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tTopLeft";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tTopRight";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tBottomLeft";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tBottomRight";
                    }
                );
                string =             (
                                    {
                        text = "\n\thttp://www.url.com";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\thttp://www.url.com";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\t1 : 2 500";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tSeb O'H (2014)";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\tUrban (school)";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\t42.87067222225,147.31143055";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\t42.8645138888888894, 147.3160527777777";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\t42.87067222222222, 147.3160527777777";
                    },
                                    {
                        text = "\n\t42.8645138888888894, 147.31143055555555";
                    }
                );
                text = "\n";
            };
            text = "\n";
            version = "1.0";
        };
```

I've tried many methods but still can't seem to get it working. So in simple my question is, how do I put a row in an `NSDictionary` into an `NSArray`.
Thanks.

Comment: There's no code here. Post the code you attempted to parse the XML, and perhaps also the XML itself. And if you're trying to parse a plist, your approach is very off course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply filter the array using `valueForKeyPath`

```
NSArray *text = [data valueForKeyPath:@"plist.dict.string.text"];
```